# VBA How to save and close workbook after time of inactivity, unless userform is open?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

This is my first time posting on this site, and would appreciate some help. I'm a member of the mrexcel forums, and have received a lot of help from those great people over there, but have not been able to find an answer to my question. At work, I've created a workbook that allows us to enter data into different worksheets via a userform. I'm trying to make this as user-friendly as I possibly can, to attempt to eliminate as many "user-errors" as possible. One issue I'm trying to avoid is a user forgetting to close the sheet when their shift is over, and locking everyone out because the workbook is read-only when another user has the file open. So, I have a code that will save and close the workbook after 40 minutes of inactivity. One issue this is causing (and it is a very minor issue, but one that has been brought up to me by one of my employees), is that every once in a while, coincidentally the user will be entering data into the userform right around that 40 minutes of inactivity, and the workbook will close before they had a chance to submit the data. I was wondering if anyone could help me modify my code so that when it reaches that 40 minutes of inactivity, before it saves and closes, it sees that the userform is open and cancels the action if it is. Here is the code that I've got. Thanks for any help I can get.

In Module 1:

```
Dim CloseTime As Date
Sub TimeSetting()
    CloseTime = Now + TimeValue("00:40:00")
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
      Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=True
End Sub
Sub TimeStop()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
      Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=False
End Sub
Sub SavedAndClose()
    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call TimeSetting
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call TimeStop
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call TimeStop
    Call TimeSetting
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `TimeStop()` sub on the `Userform_Initialize()` event, and then call the `TimeSetting()` sub when you close the userform

Comment: It amazes me how often I over-analyze things and completely over-look a simple solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if a userform is loaded by using this function:

```
Function IsUFLoaded(ByVal UFName As String) As Boolean
    Dim UForm As Object

    For Each UForm In VBA.UserForms
        If UForm.Name = UFName Then
            IsUFLoaded = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And then in `SavedAndClose` Sub:

```
Sub SavedAndClose()
    ' change userform_name to your userform name
    If IsUFLoaded("userform_name") = False Then ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not, instead of doing what you're suggesting: allowing a user to accidentally leave themselves logged in to a userform which would cause the issue you're trying to avoid, you instead *also* reset the timer with `Call TimeStop` and `Call TimeSetting` within the change events of fields in the userform?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is such a simple solution. Those are usually the ones I over-look the most. lol.